# Waiting for multiple async operations in Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nightwatch.js

I am attempting to test multiple sites for section headers being in the correct order. Of course everything is asynchronous in Nightwatch, including getting text from an element. The following code leads to the timeout never being called.

```
client.url(`www.oneofmyrealestatesites.com`);
client.waitForElementPresent("body", 5000);
var _ = require("underscore");
// This is the order I expect things to be in
var expected = ["Homes For Sale", "New Homes", "Apartments & Rentals"];
client.elements("css selector", ".listings .module-title .label", function (data) {
  var listings = [];
  data.value.forEach(function (element) {
    client.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function (result) {
      listings.push(result.value);
    })
  })
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Some of the sites have extra sections
    var diff = _.intersection(listings, expected);
    client.assert.ok(listings == diff);
  }, 5000);
});
```

It would appear that no matter how much delay I give, listings is ALWAYS empty. If I console.log listings as it's being pushed to, it *is* getting populated, so that's not the issue. `client.pause` is always ignored as well.

Is there a way to make sure that listings is populated before asserting the diff?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `async` library for such cases https://github.com/caolan/async
Docs: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md

```
var async = require("async");

/*use each, eachSeries or eachLimit - check docs for differences */
async.eachSeries(data.value, function (element, cb) {
    client.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function (result) {
      listings.push(result.value);
      // this job is done
      cb();
    });
}, function() {
    // Some of the sites have extra sections
    var diff = _.intersection(listings, expected);
    client.assert.ok(listings == diff);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout can only be called from .execute or .executeAsync because its actual javascript. The function below was only working until I used .executeAsync

Hope this works for you.

Cheers, Rody

```
 LoopQuestionsLogSymptom: function() {
        this.waitForElementVisible('.next-button', constants.timeout.medium, false);
        this.api.executeAsync(function() {
            let checkQuestion = function() {
                // GET THE ELEMENTS
                let nextButton = document.querySelectorAll('.next-button');
                let answers = document.getElementsByClassName('flex-row');
                let blueButton = document.querySelector('.blue-inverse-button');
                let doneButton = document.querySelector('#doneButton');
                let monitor = document.querySelector('.monitor');
                //CHECK THE TYPES OF QUESTIONS AND CLICK THE RIGHT BUTTONS
                if (!blueButton) {
                    answers[0].click();
                    nextButton[0].click()
                } else if(blueButton){
                    blueButton.click();
                }
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if(!doneButton) {
                        console.log('Answering another question!');
                        checkQuestion();
                    }
                    if(doneButton){
                        doneButton.click();
                    }
                    else if(monitor) {
                        console.log("Exiting?")
                        .assert(monitor);

                        return this;
                    }
                }, 2000);
            };

            // Initiating the check question function
            return checkQuestion();

        },[], function(){
            console.log('Done?')
        });
        this.waitForElementVisible('.monitor', constants.timeout.medium);
            this.assert.elementPresent('.monitor');
            this.assert.urlEquals('https://member-portal.env-dev4.vivantehealth.org/progress');
        return this;
    },
```